# Changing only the line properties inside the circle when using pie in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pie-chart

When I am segmenting a circle with pie from matplotlib I would like to change the properties of the lines only inside the circle:

```
plt.rcParams['patch.edgecolor'] = 'lightgrey' 
plt.rcParams['patch.linewidth'] = 1
```

Affect all the lines including the line of the circle itsef.

Answer (score 3):

#### Step 1 - changing 'inner' lines

As usual it is a good idea to look at the matplotlib API documentation, where we find that [`pie`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) plot provides a lot of arguments, one of which is `wedgeprops`

> wedgeprops: [ None | dict of key value pairs ]
> Dict of arguments passed to the wedge objects making the pie. For example, you can pass in wedgeprops = { ‘linewidth’ : 3 } to set the width of the wedge border lines equal to 3. For more details, look at the [doc/arguments of the wedge object](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Wedge).

One of the arguments to Wedge is `edgecolor`, another is `linewidth`.

So in total you have to call

```
plt.pie([215, 130], colors=['b', 'r'], 
                    wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1 , 'edgecolor' : 'lightgrey'} )
```

However, since this also changes the outline of the pie diagram we need...

#### Step 2 - setting circonference circle

Now, in order to get a circle around the pie, or restore the initial linestyle for the circonference of the pie, we can set a new [`Circle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle) patch with the desired properties on top of the pie.

The complete solution then looks something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
ax.axis('equal')

slices, labels = ax.pie([186, 130, 85], colors=['b', 'r','y'], 
                    wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1 , 'edgecolor' : 'lightgrey'} )

# get the center and radius of the pie wedges
center = slices[0].center
r = slices[0].r
# create a new circle with the desired properties
circle = matplotlib.patches.Circle(center, r, fill=False, edgecolor="k", linewidth=2)
# add the circle to the axes
ax.add_patch(circle)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: There is no circle, there are only wedges.

Comment: ...but we can create a circle such that it looks as if only the "inner" lines were changed. See my answer's edit.

Answer (score 2):

For a solution that works also with any pie chart, including exploded pie charts, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

data = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2]
explode = [0.05] * len(data)
labels = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:len(data)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pie = ax.pie(data, labels=labels, explode=explode)
```

use one of the following options:

**Option A**, add lines for each wedge of the pie

```
pie = ax.pie(data, labels=labels, explode=explode)

for wedge in pie[0]:
    ax.plot([wedge.center[0], wedge.r*np.cos(wedge.theta1*np.pi/180)+wedge.center[0]], [wedge.center[1], wedge.r*np.sin(wedge.theta1*np.pi/180)+wedge.center[1]], color='k')
    ax.plot([wedge.center[0], wedge.r*np.cos(wedge.theta2*np.pi/180)+wedge.center[0]], [wedge.center[1], wedge.r*np.sin(wedge.theta2*np.pi/180)+wedge.center[1]], color='k')

fig.show()
```

[image: Option A]

**Option B**, add edges to the pie wedges then overwrite the radial edge with another color (e.g. white)

```
from matplotlib import patches

pie = ax.pie(data, labels=labels, explode=explode, wedgeprops=dict(ec='k')

for wedge in pie[0]:
    arc = patches.Arc(wedge.center, 2*wedge.r, 2*wedge.r, 0, theta1=wedge.theta1, theta2=wedge.theta2, ec='w', lw=1.5)
    ax.add_patch(arc)

fig.show()
```

[image: Option B]